# How do i get data from the last row of a given column in a google spreadsheet after the form is submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to send an email to a specific person depending on the data in the last row, similar to the vlookup function. If the data entered in the form is x then send mail to joe, if data is y send mail to jack etc. I'm confused on how range selection works when there is no active range like when you have in the spreadsheet view.

```
function sendEmails() 
{   
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();


 if (data == "xxx")
 {
   sendmail //i got this
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In such situations (reacting to a form submit) when the spreadsheet is not necessarily open, you should preferably use these methods to access a sheet :

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the ID of the spreadsheet');
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];// access first sheet (0 indexed)
  var row = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Serge -

I wrote this script as you suggested, just to replace the last row with:

```
return sh.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
```

And place it inside my spreadsheet. However, the cell in the spreadsheet is not updated once  new form submissions arrive...

What should be done?

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand your question... could you elaborate please? Also:  I think you should preferably start a new question...

Comment: I found the answer myself, so I will explain the question and what workaround I found: The question is, if I write this function but it returns that data instead of emailing it, and then I call the function from within the spreadsheet, then the spreadsheet value is not updated when new form data arrives. The workaround is to write this latest value to a given range from within the function and set the function to be called every time a form is submitted.